# PLS-00222 no function with the name 'WRITE_ERROR_LOG' exists in this scope

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, error-handling

Just finished writing an error log procedure that logs errors to a table. I just finished my first exception handler and i cant compile the package due to this error.

I believe i'm getting this error when I call my write_error_log procedure.
below is the code from the package.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY AOMS.customer IS

    PROCEDURE 
customer_collateral_hist(i_Vcust_cd   IN  customer_collateral_history.cust_cd%TYPE,
                                   i_Vfromdate  IN customer_collateral_history.reg_dttm%TYPE,
                                   i_Vtodate    IN customer_collateral_history.reg_dttm%TYPE,
                                   i_Vauthstat  IN customer_collateral_history.auth_stat%TYPE,
                                   o_Cresultset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
   AS
        v_in_out_parm VARCHAR2(4000) := NULL;

 BEGIN
     OPEN o_Cresultset FOR
     SELECT auth_stat,
            buld_size,
            clos_dt,
            cnfm_dt,
            cnfm_tm,
            cnfm_user_id,
            cust_cd,
            date_seq,
            dbtr,
            dbtr_addr,
            dbtr_id,
            dbtr_tel_no,
            dbtr_zip_cd1,
            dbtr_zip_cd2,
            esta_orga,
            grnt_dt_from,
            grnt_dt_to,
            jdg_amt,
            jdg_dt,
            land_size,
            loc_addr,
            mort_amt,
            mort_chng_dt,
            mort_flag,
            mort_max_amt,
            mort_seq,
            mort_stat,
            old_key,
            ownr,
            ownr_addr,
            ownr_id,
            ownr_tel_no,
            ownr_zip_cd1,
            ownr_zip_cd2,
            prev_mort_amt,
            redm_dt,
            reg_dt,
            reg_dttm,
            reg_flag,
            reg_user_id,
            remark,
            supr_pow_flag
       FROM customer_collateral_history
      WHERE cust_cd LIKE '%'||NVL(i_Vcust_cd, cust_cd)||'%'
        AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)) >= NVL(i_Vfromdate,   TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)))
    AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)) <= NVL(i_Vtodate, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(reg_dttm, 1, 8)))
    AND auth_stat LIKE '%'||NVL(i_Vauthstat, auth_stat)||'%';
  EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN

  V_IN_OUT_PARM :=  'vcust_cd: '||i_vcust_cd||'fromdate:' ||i_vfromdate|| 'vtodate:' ||i_vtodate|| 'authstat:' || i_vauthstat||

   write_error_log(SQLERRM,dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace,V_IN_OUT_PARM);
   -- if you want to halt execution re-raise the error up the stack
   RAISE;
 END customer_collateral_hist;

END customer;
/
```

Does anyone have an idea what's causing this. The write_error_log is a stored procedure. If there is anymore information I can provide anybody with let me know.

Comment: There are few possible options: 1 - The function does not exists at all; 2- exists but it is invalid (compilation error); 3 - Exists but there are no grant to the user that is calling it. And 4 - You are using it with the wrong number/types of parameters!

Comment: I'm not calling a function but rather a procedure. Not sure how much of a difference there is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is on this line:

```
V_IN_OUT_PARM :=  'vcust_cd: '||i_vcust_cd||'fromdate:' ||i_vfromdate|| 'vtodate:' ||i_vtodate|| 'authstat:' || i_vauthstat||
```

It seems to end rather unexpectedly.  Is there something else you need to concatenate to `V_IN_OUT_PARAM` or should the last `||` be a `;`?

Because you've ended it with a `||`, it looks to Oracle as if you want to concatenate the result of calling `write_error_log` to this string.  Of course, you cannot do this because you don't have a function called `write_error_log`.